# Allow non-blank cell based on Data Validation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a data validation setup in Cell A2 with list as 'Yes' and 'No'.

If the user selects No for cell A2, the cell B2 should not be blank.
Can anyone give me the excel function for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide some code to demonstrate what you have already tried.

Comment: If "No" cell B2 should not be blank. What value should it assume then? If the user selects "No" the value of B2 will always be the same?

Comment: `=if(a2="No","","Something else")` enter the formula in B2

Comment: If the user selects the value No, then cell B2 should not be blank and excel should prompt to enter a value just like the countblank function (=COUNTBLANK(A2)=0)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a warning to user, you can format B1 with red fill color (or any color) using conditional formatting. Conditional formatting formula can be like this:

```
=AND($A1="No";$B1="")
```

Or you can prevent user answering "No" if B1 cell is empty.
In your data validation window select the "List" from Allow section then type the below formula on the "Source"

```
=IF(B1="";$G$1;G$1:$G$2)
```

Where g1's value equals "Yes" and g2's value "No". This validation will give the "Yes" option if B1 is blank and will give "Yes" and "No" option if B1 is not blank

And you can direct the user with an Input message on "Data validation" window that says that it is required to fill the B1 value in order to select "No" for A1

Apart from that if you'd like to give user a prompt without changing the b1 value, you can make an change event macro that tracks the a and b columns, but I doubt you are looking something like that